# Unable to use Get It background callback

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, flutter-dependencies, service-locator

I have a flutter app that has a background listener but I keep getting an Unhanded exception.

Here is my main()

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();
  await HomeWidget.registerBackgroundCallback(backgroundCallback);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

here is my setupLocator():

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => PreferenceProvider());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => CurrencyApi.create());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => BackupCurrencyApi.create());
  locator.registerLazySingleton<Repository>(() => RepositoryImpl(locator<PreferenceProvider>(), locator<CurrencyApi>(),locator<BackupCurrencyApi>()));
  ...
}
```

and here is my backgroundCallback:

```
Future<void> backgroundCallback(Uri? uri) async {
  Repository repository = locator<RepositoryImpl>();
  ...
}
```

I get the following error where I try to retrieve the Repository in the background call:

> E/flutter (11326): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: 'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory
> with  type RepositoryImpl is not registered inside GetIt.  E/flutter
> (11326): (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead
> of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your callback function with `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` and ensure all dependencies are initialized (such as GetIt).

More details at https://github.com/ABausG/home_widget/pull/99